# Android do i need to set each object to null when done using it?

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have this object I've created which holds references to some other objects:

```
public class ListHandler {

    private AppVariables app; //AppVariables instance
    private Extra extra; //the extra argument represanting the list
    private ArrayList<FacebookUser> arrayList; //the array list associate with the list given
    private Comparator<FacebookUser> comparator; //the comparator of the list
    private String emptyText; //list empty text

    /**
     * Constructor - initialize a new instance of the listHandler
     * @param app the current {@link AppVariables} instance
     * @param extra the {@link Extra} {@link Enum} of the list
     */
    public ListHandler(AppVariables app, Extra extra)
    {
        this.app = app;
        this.extra = extra;
         //set the array list to match the list given in the arguments
        setArrayList(); 
        setComparator();
        setEmptyTest();
    }
    /**
     * Clear all resources being held by this object
     */
    public void clearListHandler()
    {
        this.arrayList = null;
        this.comparator = null;
        this.app = null;
        this.emptyText = null;
        this.extra = null;      
    }
```

I've built the `clearListHandler()` method in order to set all the objects I'm using to `null` when finished using the `ListHandler`.

Is it necessary? Do I need to clear all the objects in order to get them garbage collected later or will the GC know that this object is no longer in use since the object which initialized it is no longer in use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage Collection is pretty smart, and you generally don't need to explicitly set objects to null (though it helps in some cases when using Bitmaps).

An Object becomes eligible for Garbage collection or GC if its not reachable from any live threads or any static refrences in other words you can say that an object becomes eligible for garbage collection if its all references are null. Cyclic dependencies are not counted as reference so if Object A has reference of object B and object B has reference of Object A and they don't have any other live reference then both Objects A and B will be eligible for Garbage collection. 
Generally an object becomes eligible for garbage collection in Java in following cases:

1. All references of that object explicitly set to null e.g. object = null
2. Object is created inside a block and reference goes out scope once control exit that block.
3. Parent object set to null, if an object holds reference of another object and when you set container object's reference null, child or contained object automatically becomes eligible for garbage collection.
4. If an object has only live references via WeakHashMap it will be eligible for garbage collection.

You can find more details on Garbage Collection [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html#ixzz2OqNBx2W9).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that. The garbage collector will determine automatically when its best to clear all the objects.
Try reading [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).

Comment: Oracle has nothing to do with Android. Here's [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)).

Comment: But Android is still Java and Dalvik is just another JVM. The links are explaning GC basics which are common to any VM/JVM.

Comment: ~"**garbage collector will determine automatically**".  Since when are garbage collectors predictable and reliable?  Especially on Android...

Answer (score 0):

No.  The Dalvik/Java Virtual Machine will allocate memory, and de-allocate memory as need be.

There is no problem with what you are doing, it's just unnecessary.